# Doing a PHP in_array() but with a needle of one another array()

Tags: php

I need something like `in_array()` for search if at least one of `$foo` is in `$bar`array, like:

```
$foo = array("ESD", "RED", "IOP");
$bar = array("IOD", "MNP", "JDE", "RED");

if(in_array($foo, $bar)) // true because RED is in $foo and in $bar
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you want `array_intersect()`:

```
$matches = array_intersect($foo, $bar);
```

`$matches` will return an array of all items that are in both arrays, so you can:

- Check to see if there are no matches with `empty($matches)`
- Read the number of matches with `count($matches)`
- Read the values of the intersections if you need to

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Example for your case:

```
$foo = array("ESD", "RED", "IOP");
$bar = array("IOD", "MNP", "JDE", "RED");

// Just cast to boolean
if ((bool) array_intersect($foo, $bar)) // true because RED is in $foo and in $bar
```

Comment: didn't know this function, thanks :-) But it still takes 2 steps where it could take only one if you use the function I gave. However that only makes sense if you want to use it multiple times, otherwise your solution do.

Comment: @PENDO, you can just [cast it to boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) as demonstrated in the update to get a TRUE or FALSE return. It's good to take advantage of the built-in functionality when possible, plus this function returns the array itself which can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Best is to create your own function if it always is about 2 arrays;

```
function in_both_arrays($key, $arrone, $arrtwo)
{
  return (in_array($key, $arrone) && in_array($key, $arrtwo)) ? true : false ;
}
```

Comment: The variable name `$key` is confusing.

Comment: @PENDO, `in_array()` returns boolean, so no need for the ternary operator and explicit TRUE/FALSE return value. `return in_array($key, $arrone) && in_array($key, $arrtwo)` would do the same thing.

Comment: @bazmegakapa, what for? It is the key your looking for?

Comment: @PENDO Because in an array a `key` has a special meaning, and here you are looking for `value`s not `key`s. Not a crucial thing though...

Comment: my bad, thought I was looking for keys at the time I wrote this comment.. you're completely right, `$value` would be a better fit ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

```
function in_arrays($needles, $haystack)
{
    foreach ((array) $needles as $needle)
    {
        if (in_array($needle, $haystack) === true)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: he needs the needle inside both arrays. I came up with this function aswel at first but then noticed what he really needed :-)

Comment: @PENDO: Seems like you're right, the "at least one of $foo is in $bar" part induced me in error.

Comment: Same here, mistaked by that sentence aswell.